# How to sort/search by property value in emacs orgmode and/or agenda view?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have org-mode TODO items  and I am using property to enter the entry-date via org-capture-templates.  This is date of entry and not scheduled date.  I have...

`:PROPERTIES:
:Entered: [2015-08-12 Wed 17:07]
:END:`

Now I need to search all the item that were entered on or after certain dates.
I can also use the sorting by entry timestamp. 

Thanks.

Comment: For searching by property value, see the advanced searching tutorial from the manual:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  For sorting by property value, I do not believe that feature is built-in.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to some nice features.  Some combination of regex leads me to desired search solutions, but not the sorting one. Perhaps it may be easy enough to write some elisp for someone.

Comment: Sadly, the sorting is not so easy.  `org-mode` calculates certain values during the searching process and places text-properties with those values on the data that has been gathered, which is then sorted with a starting point such as `org-entries-lessp`.  The three (3) main searching functions are already missing value calculations and text property assignments for many of the options in the `org-agenda-sorting-stragegy`, which is why there are threads asking why sorting doesn't seem to work.  Someone on the mailing list responded to my inquiry by stating that *some* fixes are in the works.

Comment: The project would entail assigning a value to the property drawer entry -- e.g., name/title of the entry; then assign it a text property that can be sorted with let's say `alpha-up` and `alpha-down`.  However, the entry might be a number, in which case a different sort would be needed.  Or, the entry might be a date, in which case a conversion would be needed from date to number to use `ts-up` and `ts-down`, and so on.  All  doable, but would take time for anyone motivated to enable those features and figure out a way to decide which value to assign.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `org-sparse-tree` (C-c /).  It won't work with timestamps in a property, but you can put timestamps in the headline or on the line below and org-sparse-tree will find it.

Comment: That will not solve it.   I don't want to put timestamp in headlines or as a free text. I am looking for sortable solution. So, I can see what task I entered last week, and haven't moved forward etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) - it's a command that works similarly to isearch.  It will automatically reveal any hidden outlines that match. The input `15 8 12` will actually match `2015-08-12` since single spaces act as wild cards.

Example screenshot:

[image: swiper.png]
<sub>(source: [oremacs.com](http://oremacs.com/download/org-mode-swiper.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For sorting by property... Use `M-x org-sort-entries [RET] r`. Change `r` to `R` for reversing order. For more on `org-sort-entries`, use `C-h f org-sort-entries`.

Answer (score 0):

Use C-c a m

then enter:

```
 Entered>="<2016-06-01>"
```

This will search items with property "Entered" with date values exactly equals or after [2016-06-01]. It will not sort the items by newest or oldest.

Comment: org-agenda -> Match a TAGS/PROP/TODO query - For those of us with non-standard keybindings